# Error faced during SSO on Internet explorer

Tags: azure-active-directory

We have a custom SSO implementation with Azure AD.
It works perfectly when we access for the first time through Internet Explorer, but on trying access again it shows the following error.

> AADSTS75011: Authentication method 'WindowsIntegrated' by which the
>   user authenticated with the service doesn't match requested
>   authentication method 'Password, ProtectedTransport'

We have looked into the Azure AD configuration's but no success.

Comment: We have tried to access the Error codes for Azure AD aswell but couldn't find Error code: 75011

Comment: How did you implement the SSO? And I found the same error from [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/534397b2-30bb-4cae-83c1-173eb7b59b65/azure-ad-custom-web-app-sso?forum=WindowsAzureAD), is the suggestion helpful?

Comment: I have implemented a custom SSO. And this error was faced when SP-initiated SSO was in use as the desired Authentication method was "Password Protected" but user was always transmitting "Windows Integrated".
But I was later able to solve the issue.

Comment: @VishalJain we are facing a similar issue, can you please share the fix.